# Problem with setting up Android SDK

Tags: android

I have just freshly installed Fedora 15 and installed eclipse via the "Add/Remove Software".I proceeded to install the Helios plugins via `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios` then followed the directions in installing the Android SDK.

I am now stuck when trying to download a package from the `Android AVD and SDK Manager`, the progress bar just stops on "Validate XML" and doesn't budge. I tried leaving it overnight hoping that at least it might throw an error but it remained the same.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I noticed since I installed Helios the following error pops up when starting up eclipse, I am unsure if it is contributing towards the problem :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is networking working properly? If not, the xml might not have downloaded completely, which would make it invalid.

Comment: The network seems fine, I've tried this multiple times and at first it downloads some files before trying to validate the XML